# Filling table from DataTable in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

as the question says I am trying to fill a table in the view from a data table. So far this is my code in the controller:

```
DataSet dsTemplates = new DataSet();

        string qryTemplets = "";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter daTemplate = new SqlDataAdapter(qryTemplets, conn);
        daTemplate.Fill(dsTemplates, "FileInfo");
        DataTable dtTemplates = new DataTable();
        dtTemplates = dsTemplates.Tables[0];

        List<Models.GameModels.UserList> tables = dtTemplates.Rows.AsEnumerable()
       .Select(t => new Models.GameModels.UserList
         {
           Name = row["Name"],
           Record = row["Record"]
         })
             .ToList();

        conn.Close();
        return View(tables);
```

Its giving me the following exception:

> 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments

Is this the best way to get render a table with multiple rows? Is there a workaround for my error? Thanks in advance.
What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to project the rows into your `UserList` object:

```
List<UserList> tables = dtTemplates.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(t => new UserList
    {
        Name = t["Name"],
        Record = t["Record"]
    }).ToList();
```